# Add function to controller in laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, controller

This might not be best practice- however my functions will be rather comprehensive and used by additional controllers, thus I would like to separate them from the controller's public class. (what is best practice? I just want to load the functions to specific pages/controllers.)

Laravel 7

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    function add($a, $b) {
        print($a + $b);
    }

    public function show($id) {
            add(1,2) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't perform logic in the controller.

I recommend you to create a `Calculator` folder for example where you store the sum, something like this:

The controller:

```php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Calculator;

final class HomeController extends Controller
{
                     // $id not needed, although, if you are going to use it,
                     // try to declare the type!
    public function show() {
        return (new Calculator())->add(1, 2);
    }
}
```

And the calculation class:

```php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Calculator;

final class Calculator
{
    public function add(float $firstOp, float $secondOp): float
    {
        return $firstOp + $secondOp;
    }
}
```

**PS**: Do not print in the controller, you have to follow the SRP (Single Responsibility Principle)! :)
You can replace the `return (new Calculator())->add(1, 2);` in the `show()` method by a `dd(new Calculator())->add(1, 2));` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a solution for using a trait a common practice in Laravel.

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use  App\Traits\MySpecialFunctions;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    use MySpecialFunctions;
}
```

```php
namespace App\Traits;

trait MySpecialFunctions {
    function add($a, $b) {
        print($a + $b);
    }

    public function show($id) {
            add(1,2) 
    }
}
```